# HTML input number with parseInt onchange

Tags: javascript, html, input, types, numbers

I'm using an `input type="number"` in my form. I trigger an `onchange` event to get its value.

But when I write '2a' it says the value were empty. So I can't even put an `parseInt()` around to get the '2' integer, what I would like to.

It works with `input type="text"` of course, but I would also like to use the min max attributes of the number type to easify form validation. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: `<input>` elements with type "number" (in browsers that support it) insist that the value be a valid number. Anything that's not a number will be treated as an empty value.

Comment: As Pointy mentioned, inputs of type `number` restrict the user to enter only numbers, that way you don't even need to call `parseInt()` in your script.

Comment: @Arkantos, He must be setting value like `value="2a"`

Comment: yes, but I wanted to use the value before submitting the form. I simply write the value into the input field. But to eliminate false client behaviour I would like to parse the value, so the script also works if like a '#' is entered into the field by accident. simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/kn6mLvxy/2/

Comment: @RayonDabre.. Yeah I got that but if he really needs a number with some  (min,max) boundaries, then he should stick to type='number' instead of doing additional work with type='text' and code to verify boundaries. Ofcourse, type=`number` works only in HTML5 complaint browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `keydown` instead of `change` to do that:

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  var char = e.key || String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) || String.fromCharCode(e.charCode);
  if (!/[0-9]/.test(char)) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="number" min="0" max="100" placeholder="Insert a number">
```

Comment: hm yes that would work. The only thing not working would be copy pasting, but in my case its not required.

Answer (score 0):

The type number of input elements not mean that you can't write other types of characters in it, only are for make the form element that contain the input valid or invalid in html context, I suggest that use Regex or character check in a javascript function linked to onkeydown event in the input, with which you can control absolutely the character that you can insert or not in that input. If you use a framework javascript, there are some function to help you, in other case you could program that by yourself in a little javascript function.
For example this is a regexp for integer/decimal that allow positive and negative numbers.

```
"^[-+]?([0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?|\.[0-9]+)$"
```